# RedirectToAction direct to default controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to change my login redirect from

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

To

```
return RedirectToAction("Foo", "Profile");
```

The Foo action return a view. 
The problem is that I still get the home/index.

Do I need to change the routing?

The RouteConfig is like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "NotFound",
        url: "{*catchall}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );

}
```

Comment: Foo action is in ProfileController ?

Comment: Yes. The Foo method is in the ProfileController.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the redirect after login redirect to the root '/' url.
You can reset this via your routes. 
Something like this below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Foo", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NotFound",
    url: "{*catchall}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Foo" }
);
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change these routes from database parameters? 
I can’t have several default routes etc.

Comment: I have tried this out, and it still redirect to the HomeController.. How do I track the routing?

Comment: That is very strange because the  homecontroller should not be linked to the routes anymore as a default.
You can install routedebugger as a nuget package to follow up on the routes:  http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx/

Did you by any chance set the [Route] attribute somewhere in the home controller?

Comment: I will try this routetracker. I shouldent set the route to anything else in the HomeController or other places. But I have some RedirectToAction im the home and profile controller.

Comment: It still hits catchall in routeconfig. It works all other places, but this do not.